# Left outer join between 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables .

1. Seat Table
2. Local Employee
3. Foreign Employee.

There is one common column between Seat and Local, person_id which tells which person is seated in which seat.

In the same way between Seat and Foreign table, also person_id.

I am able to get the required data betwee Seat and Local ...and Seat and Foreign using left outer join getting null seats for vacant and personid for occupied seats.

My question is, can I get a single query mapping seat table with both tables and get a consolidated report?

The query am using now is:

```
select seat.apeh05_person_id_k
      ,seat.apeh18_seat_r seatNo
      , seat.apeh17_floor_k  seatFloor
      ,vendor.apeh15_cds_d cdsid
      , vendor.apeh15_first_n firstname
      , vendor.apeh15_last_n lastname
      ,vendor.apeh15_supervisor_cds_d ll6cdsid
      ,vendor.apeh15_ll5_cds_d ll5cdsid
      , vendor.apeh15_ll4_cds_d ll4cdsid 
 from iapeh18_seat seat ,
       IAPEH15_VENDOR_EMPLOYEE  vendor
 where seat.apeh05_person_id_k = vendor.apeh15_vendor_employee_k (+) 
 order by   seat.apeh05_person_id_k asc
```

the other query is:

```
select seat.apeh05_person_id_k
      ,seat.apeh18_seat_r seatNo
      , seat.apeh17_floor_k  seatFloor
      ,local.apeh09_cds_d cdsid
      ,local.apeh09_first_n firstname
      , local.apeh09_last_n lastname
      ,local.apeh09_supervisor_cds_d ll6cdsid
      ,local.apeh09_ll5_cds_d ll5cdsid
      ,  local.apeh09_ll4_cds_d ll4cdsid 
 from iapeh18_seat seat 
        , IAPEH09_LOCAL_EMPLOYEE local
 where seat.apeh05_person_id_k = local.apeh05_candidate_k (+)
 order by seat.apeh05_person_id_k asc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a more effective version of Remko Jansen's answer

```
select seat.apeh05_person_id_k person_id
      ,seat.apeh18_seat_r seatNo
      ,seat.apeh17_floor_k  seatFloor
      ,employee.apeh15_cds_d cdsid
      ,employee.apeh15_first_n firstname
      ,employee.apeh15_last_n lastname
      ,employee.apeh15_supervisor_cds_d ll6cdsid
      ,employee.apeh15_ll5_cds_d ll5cdsid
      ,employee.apeh15_ll4_cds_d ll4cdsid 
  from iapeh18_seat seat ,
    (select * from IAPEH15_VENDOR_EMPLOYEE  
      union all
     select * from IAPEH09_LOCAL_EMPLOYEE
    ) employee
   where seat.apeh05_person_id_k = employee.apeh05_candidate_k (+)
   order by apeh05_person_id_k
```

At first unioning and joining after that - save the trouble of doing distinct rows (quite expensive operation).

Comment: Thanks knagaev..am accepting your answer because it removed the duplicates from seat table resulting between the 3 tables..Thanks Remko also for taking us to the correct path..

Comment: Of course you need "employee" predicate instead of "vendor" in my sample - my careless mistake for copy-paste :)

Comment: @knagaev Fixed the "employee" prefix for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can, like this, but I'm not sure if this is what you want. What do you want to happen if both local and vendor have a person with the id in apeh05_person_id_k?

Also, you would normally want a foreign key constraint, which is now impossible, because seat.apeh05_person_id_k can contain ids from both tables.

All in all, I think this is what you asked for, but I think your design is flawed.

```
select 
  seat.*, -- Omitted field list for readability
  nvl2(local.apeh05_candidate_k, local.WhateverField, vendor.WhateverField) as WhateverField,
  nvl2(local.apeh05_candidate_k, local.YetAnotherField, vendor.YetAnotherField) as YetAnotherField
from 
  iapeh18_seat seat
  LEFT JOIN IAPEH15_VENDOR_EMPLOYEE vendor
    ON seat.apeh05_person_id_k = vendor.apeh15_vendor_employee_k
  LEFT JOIN IAPEH09_LOCAL_EMPLOYEE local
    ON seat.apeh05_person_id_k = local.apeh05_candidate_k
order by   
  seat.apeh05_person_id_k asc
```

Comment: Hi Goleztrol,The local and vendor employee table cannot have the same person_id.I need all data from seat table whether personn_id is null or not null. If not null, i need to get data from the corresponding table where it is present.

Comment: One more info..i need the same column data from both local and vendor tables...no duplicates needed

Comment: Little modification: Use nvl2 to check if record is found in the first table. If so, use FieldX from the first table, otherwise use it from the second table. I've modified the code.

Answer (score 1):

Since both queries contain the exact same columns you can merge them together with a UNION statement, like this:

```
select seat.apeh05_person_id_k person_id
      ,seat.apeh18_seat_r seatNo
      ,seat.apeh17_floor_k  seatFloor
      ,vendor.apeh15_cds_d cdsid
      ,vendor.apeh15_first_n firstname
      ,vendor.apeh15_last_n lastname
      ,vendor.apeh15_supervisor_cds_d ll6cdsid
      ,vendor.apeh15_ll5_cds_d ll5cdsid
      ,vendor.apeh15_ll4_cds_d ll4cdsid 
  from iapeh18_seat seat ,
       IAPEH15_VENDOR_EMPLOYEE  vendor
 where seat.apeh05_person_id_k = vendor.apeh15_vendor_employee_k (+) 
UNION
select seat.apeh05_person_id_k person_id
      ,seat.apeh18_seat_r seatNo
      ,seat.apeh17_floor_k  seatFloor
      ,local.apeh09_cds_d cdsid
      ,local.apeh09_first_n firstname
      ,local.apeh09_last_n lastname
      ,local.apeh09_supervisor_cds_d ll6cdsid
      ,local.apeh09_ll5_cds_d ll5cdsid
      , local.apeh09_ll4_cds_d ll4cdsid 
 from iapeh18_seat seat 
        , IAPEH09_LOCAL_EMPLOYEE local
 where seat.apeh05_person_id_k = local.apeh05_candidate_k (+)
 order by person_id
```

The UNION operator returns all **distinct** rows that appear in either result.
See: [The UNION [ALL], INTERSECT, MINUS Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)